# Is it possible to access data / html context from root Vue 3 component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have used Vue in the past but am struggling with how to pass information / args to a root Vue 3 component. In my html, I'd like to have something like this:

```html
  <div class="nav-app" nav="some-nav-jht"></div>
```

where in my `mounted()`, I could access `nav` via something like this:

```
mounted(){
    console.log('here is nav: ' + this.nav);
```

How would I do this? I am doing this by loading Vue off of CDN (no webpack etc...).

Comment: using `ref` you can `<input ref="input">` and then in `onMounted(() => {
  input.value.focus()
})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, [template refs](https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.31/dist/vue.global.prod.js) enable accessing an element from `<script>`.

Apply the [`ref`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html#ref) attribute to the element with a name (e.g., `"navapp"`):

```html
<div id="app">                             
  <div class="nav-app" nav="some-nav-jht" ref="navapp">⋯</div>
</div>
```

Then in your `mounted` hook, access the ref via `this.$refs.REFNAME`:

```html
<script>
Vue.createApp({
  mounted() {
    const navapp = this.$refs.navapp
    console.log('here is nav: ' + navapp.getAttribute('nav'))
  }
}).mount('#app')
</script>
```

```js
Vue.createApp({
  mounted() {
    const navapp = this.$refs.navapp
    console.log('here is nav: ' + navapp.getAttribute('nav'))
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.31/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div ref="navapp" nav="some-nav-jht">Hello world</div>
</div>
```